# How to join Azure VM to AAD in a scripted way?

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-server-2019

*Clarification: This is about joining to Azure Active Directory - but not the Directory Services under the AAD.*

I have a Server 2019 Azure VM - not joined to any AAD. The subscription is tied to Tenant X. I would like to "Azure AD join" this VM to a different AAD, belonging to Tenant Y. The scenario is to enable a user from tenant Y be able to use his/her credentials to login to this VM.

If you have ideas on how to do this in a scripted way - in the same tenant. That is welcome too.